# Regex.Split string into substrings by a delimiter while preserving whitespace

Tags: c#, regex, string, whitespace

I created a Regex to split a string by a delimiter (`$`), but it's not working the way I want.

```
var str = "sfdd fgjhk fguh      $turn.bak.orm $hahr*____f";
var list = Regex.Split(str, @"(\$\w+)").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList();

foreach (var item in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output:

```
"sfdd fgjhk fguh      "
"$turn"
".bak.orm "
"$hahr"
"*____f"
```

The problem is `\w+` is not matching any periods or stars. Here's the output I want:

```
"sfdd fgjhk fguh      "
"$turn.bak.orm"
" "
"$hahr*____f"
```

Essentially, I want to split a string by `$` and make sure `$` appears at the beginning of a substring and nowhere else (it's okay for a substring to be `$` only). I also want to make sure whitespace characters are preserved as in the first substring, but any match should not contain whitespace as in the second and fourth cases. I don't care for case sensitivity.

Comment: Try  `(\$\w+(?:[^\s\w]+\w+)*)` or `(\$(?:\w+(?:[^\s\w]+\w+)*)?)` (or even `(\$\S*)`) if `$` matches are expected.

Comment: Well, `(\$\S*)` or `(\$\S+)` seems to work for you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew These work for this use case, but they don't work if I put a `$` after `turn`. I'd like to see two matches in that case: `$turn` and `$.bak.orm`

Comment: `(\$[^\s$]*)` then? See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5c%24%5b%5e%5cs%24%5d*%29&i=sfdd+fgjhk+fguh++++++%24turn.bak.orm+%24hahr*____f+%24turn%24.bak.orm).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Awesome. This seems to be working. Can you post an answer with an explanation? Also, I'd like to know if I can expand this to include two delimiters, say `$` and `€` at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want to split with a pattern that starts with a dollar and then has any 0 or more chars other than whitespace and dollar chars:

```
var list = Regex.Split(s, @"(\$[^\s$]*)")
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
        .ToList();
```

**Details**

- `(` - start of a capturing group (so that `Regex.Split` tokenized the string, could keep the matches inside the resulting array)

  - `\$` - a dollar sign
  - `[^\s$]*` - a negated character class matching 0 or more chars other than whitespace (`\s`) and dollar symbols
- `)`  - end of the capturing group.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5C%24%5B%5E%5Cs%24%5D*%29&i=sfdd%20fgjhk%20fguh%20%20%20%20%20%20%24turn.bak.orm%20%24hahr*____f%20%24turn%24.bak.orm):

[image]

To include a second delimiter, you may use `@"([€$][^\s€$]*)"`.